# Strange Texture Behavior C++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, rendering, bmp

I'm currently taking a C++ Game Libraries class, and for this class it's been our quarter long project to build a renderer that supports a variety of things. For the current lab our instructor gave us a tutorial on loading in a bmp into OpenGL manually, and applying it to our geometries.

Tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

After following this tutorial step by step my textures are having some interesting behaviors. I've gone to other classmates, upperclassmen, and multiple instructors. None of them have an idea of what is happening. Considering that practically every one's code is identical for this Lab, and I'm the only one having this problem, I can't help but be confused.

I'm using the following OBJ, and texture. I convert the OBJ into a binary file in an OBJ converter that I built myself. My renderer takes in this binary file and sends down the data to OpenGL vertex buffers.

OBJ and Texture: http://www.models-resource.com/playstation_2/ratchetclank/model/6662/

My friend and I have the same binary file structure, so I gave him a copy of my binary file to check if the UVs were correct. His renders a perfectly textured chicken, while mind renders a chicken that looks like the texture was squished horizontally to 1/16th the length of the model, then repeated a bunch of times. I would post images, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation to do so. Over the weekend I'l do my best to increase my reputation, because I really think that it would help to visually see my problem.

I would post my source code, however this project is approaching about 16,000 lines of code, and I doubt anyone is willing to search through that to find a stranger's problem.

Any suggestions would be helpful, I'm primarily curious on common mistakes that can be made when working with OpenGL textures, or .bmps in general.

Thank Ya.

//-----Edit One-----//

My friend's result

[image: One]

My result

[image]

I'm afraid that I'm not allowed to use other libraries. I probably should have mentioned that in my initial post.

Here is the code where I am loading in the bmp, I heard from one of the upper class-man at my school that I was ignoring something called bit depth. I know that the tutorial is pretty bad, and I'd rather learn to do it right, than to just barely scrape by. If any one has a good resource on this subject, I would greatly appreciate being pointed in that direction.

```
unsigned char header[54];
unsigned int dataPos;
unsigned int width, height;
unsigned int imageSize; 
unsigned char * data;

FILE * file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
if (!file)
{
    printf("\nImage could not be opened");
    exit(1);
}

if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54){
    printf("\nNot a correct BMP file");
    exit(1);
}

if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M'){
    printf("\nNot a correct BMP file");
    exit(1);
}

dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

if (imageSize == 0) imageSize = width * height * 3;
if (dataPos == 0) dataPos = 54;

data = new unsigned char[imageSize];

fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);

fclose(file);

glGenTextures(1, &m_textureID);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

I currently am using shaders. I have both a fragment, and a vertex shader that are identical to the shaders described in the tutorial. I am both verifying each of them and making sure that they are compiling.

//-----Edit Two-----//

So I took durhass' suggestion, and set my color equal to a vec3(0.0, uv.x, uv.y) where uv is a vec2 that holds my texture coordinates, and this is what I get.

[image]

So I think I can see the root of the problem. I think that I am not storing my uvs correctly in my gl buffer. I don't think its a problem with the binary file's UVs considering that it works fine with my friend's engine. Il look into this, thank you for the suggestion, this just might lead to a fix!

Comment: Post your code where you load the texture, this error sounds like you have an Stride problem

Comment: You can also upload your image somewhere else, and link to it here. Then we can at least see. Also, are you using shaders?

Comment: That tutorials texture loading code has a number of serious issues. For one it completely neglects setting the OpenGL pixel unpacking parameters. This can result in a distorted appearance of the loaded texture (actually the load it completely corrupt). Another issue is, that it works only with the (small) set of DIB/BMP files which match that bare bones, just-get-the-essentials-done DIB file reader. For example the DIB height header might be negative to indicate an inverted scanline ordering. DIB files allow some internal striding. All of that is ignored by the code you used.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use some mature image file loader library. It's takes some work to get image file loaders working properly. There are libraries like SOIL which do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Make sure your tex coords are correctly forwarded to the frag shader, i.e. by visualizing them as colors.

Comment: I think your latest update moves the focus from the texture loading to the vertex attrib pointer setup and the shaders itself. It looks _a bit_ as if two components of the object coordinates end up as tex coords as well, You should include the relevant code parts, though.

Comment: Fixed my problems, I didn't post the code, because I knew the problem as soon as I saw the uvs as colors. Thank ya. :D My issue was that I was assigning my attribute pointer incorrectly.